# Hide many elements on d3 javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

i want to hide all elements on map.  i have hide/show button code like :

```
 svg.append("text")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", height + margin.top + 10)
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .on("click", function(){
        // Determine if current line is visible
        var active   = AxisX.active ? false : true,
          newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
        // Hide or show the elements
        d3.select("#AxisX").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        d3.select("#AxisY").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        d3.select("#cham").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        d3.select("#hop").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        // Update whether or not the elements are active
        AxisX.active = active;
      })

      .text("Hide/Show");
```

First I tried hide entire body by putting the code that similar with above code which instead using those IDs ,i use body ID to hide it  but it will hide my button too. I dont want that. So now i try hide all elements x-axis ,y-axis, dots and rectanges . But when i use above code ,it wont hide all the dots or rectanges ,it just hide x-axis , y-axis, one dot and one rectanges. What should i do to call the ID of all dots or rectanges. Thanks

My code

```
d3.csv("year1.csv", function(error, data) {

  // change string (from CSV) into number format
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Attr15 = +d.Attr15;
    d.Attr25 = +d.Attr25;
//    console.log(d);
});


  // don't want dots overlapping axis, so add in buffer to data domain
  xScale.domain([d3.min(data, xValue)-1, d3.max(data, xValue)+1]);
  yScale.domain([d3.min(data, yValue)-1, d3.max(data, yValue)+1]);

  // x-axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("id", "AxisX")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)

    svg.append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("x", width)
      .attr("y", -6)
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Attr25");


  // y-axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .attr('id', "AxisY")
      .call(yAxis)

    svg.append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Attr15");

  // draw dots
  svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", 3.5)
      .attr("id","cham")
      .attr("cx", xMap)
      .attr("cy", yMap)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(cValue(d));})
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          tooltip.transition()
               .duration(200)
               .style("opacity", .9);
          tooltip.html(d.class + "<br/> (" + xValue(d)
            + ", " + yValue(d) + ")")
               .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
               .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          tooltip.transition()
               .duration(500)
               .style("opacity", 0);
      });

  // draw legend
  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("id","hop")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  // draw legend colored rectangles
  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  // draw legend text
  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d;});

      svg.append("text")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", height + margin.top + 10)
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .on("click", function(){
        // Determine if current line is visible
        var active   = AxisX.active ? false : true,
          newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
        // Hide or show the elements
        d3.select("#AxisX").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        d3.select("#AxisY").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        d3.select("#cham").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        d3.select("#hop").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        // Update whether or not the elements are active
        AxisX.active = active;
      })

      .text("Hide/Show");


});
```

Comment: IDs are **unique**: don't set the same ID to all the circles. Use class instead: `d3.select(".dot").style("opacity", newOpacity);`

Comment: @GerardoFurtado i tried but it still just hide one dot and one rectange

Comment: My bad, I copied your line and paid attention only to the ID/class issue. Now I see that there is a second error there: you're using `select`, but you should use `selectAll` instead: `d3.selectAll(".dot").style("opacity", newOpacity);`.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado thank you so much man . It really worked